# Wavelength, frequency, and radars

Tags: resource-recommendations, frequency, wavelength, radio-frequency, radar

I'm doing a high school paper on the effects of frequency alterations on a radar image.  Can someone recommend a book which I can use?

Comment: Finding sources on your own is part of the assignment.